# What is the best way to name REST resources when returning same resource but using different DTO?

Tags: rest, naming-conventions, naming

I'm curious what is the best way of returning the same resource but using different DTOs.
For example, I have a user class:

```
public class User {
   private String name;
   private String surname;
   private String age;
}
```

The list of users is available under url:

```
/users
```

Some other view needs list of users but without age, so, I would like to return list of UserDTO.

```
public class UserDTO {
   private String name;
   private String surname;
}
```

What is the proper way of defining url?

```
/userDtos - this is bad, because I can have more than one DTOs for representing users,
/users/dto - this is also bad
/users?name=true,surname=true - this one is also bad, it indicates that we are filtering the result, but we are not; we're just filtering fields.
```

For sure someone already had this problem before, but I couldn't find anything on the Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar concept is called partial response which provide an option to let client to specify which fields to include in the response using the query parameters like:
:

```
/user?fields=name,surename
```

Basically you define a syntax for you own query language to represent a selection of fields. [Here](https://opensource.zalando.com/restful-api-guidelines/#157) and [Google Cloud API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/performance#partial-response) are some examples.

By taking this concept to a more coarse-grained level , you can use query parameter "view" to define different predefined combination of fields such as:

```
/users              //default view if no "view" query parameter is specified
/users?view=admin   //maybe this view will not show age field
/users?view=hr      //maybe this view only show the fields that are accessible to HR
```